# Write new row based on space-separated values in csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file looking like this:

```
column1 column2   column3                        
  a       b       value1 value2 value3
  a       z       value4 value5 value6
  s       t       value7
```

I want to separate 'column3' separated by space so that the column only has one value. The rest of the row would be repeated.
Here is an example of the output I would like to get:

```
column1 column2    column3  
  a       b        value1 
  a       b        value2 
  a       b        value3
```

Please note that I found an answer for similar question but using pandas which I do not want to use.

Any solution would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: unrelated but out of curiosity - why would you not want to use pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

data = []
with open(filename) as csvfile:              #Read SRC
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)   
    data.append(next(reader))   #Get header
    for row in reader:          #Iterate each line
        temp = []               #Temp list
        for i in row[-1].strip().split():
            temp.append(row[:-1] + [i])
        data.extend(temp)

with open(filename2, "w", newline='') as outfile:   #Write file
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Just as an update, when I added this code in an AWS lambda function, it keptbeing executed indefinitely, is this causing an infinite loop?

Comment: The above snippet will definitely not create an infinite look. Must be with the AWS lambda fun.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do it "manually" you can split by `column3` by space, and create rows for every value, with the same `column1` and `column2` value.

example:

```py
csv_text = """
column1,column2,column3                        
a,b,value1 value2 value3
a,z,value4 value5 value6
s,t,value7
"""

result = ["column1,column2,column3"]
for line in csv_text.splitlines(keepends=False)[2:]:
    col1, col2, col3 = line.split(",")
    for val in col3.split(" "):
        result.append(",".join((col1, col2, val)))


print("\n".join(result))
```

Outputs:

```
column1,column2,column3
a,b,value1
a,b,value2
a,b,value3
a,z,value4
a,z,value5
a,z,value6
s,t,value7
```

(you can of course write it to a file or anything else you need, the point here is the body of the loop)